# run remote command to save debian package list

Tags: debian, backup, command, remote, dpkg

I'd like to backup the package list(dpkg) of some remote computers to a backup server: all of them running Debian. I already configured the rsa key to login remotely as root on the other computers without authentication. How can I run a command like "dpkg --get-selections > file" on the remote computers to save the package list, so my backup server can copy those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your hostnames in a file, each on a separate line, then ...

```
for h in $(cat <file>); do ssh $h dpkg --get-selections >/tmp/$h.dpkg; done
```